# What is it called when we set the data type of a variable to be the same as the class name?

Tags: java, linked-list

As you can tell I'm new to java. I watched a couple of  introductory courses and now I came across making linked lists with fields having the same datatype as the class. For example this code:

```
    public class CupNode {
private int number;
private int capacity;
private CupNode next;

public CupNode(int number, int capacity) {
    this.number = number;
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.next=null;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}

public void setNumber(int number) {
    this.number = number;
}

public int getCapacity() {
    return capacity;
}

public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
}
    }
```

In the 4th line it says private CupNode next;
I know about integers, double, string etc.. but I never came across using the class name as a data type. So I'm wondering what is it called when we use a class name as a datatype so I can search for tutorials to understand what it means.

Also, why can't we define cupNode as string for example?

Comment: Java is a strongly typed language, and a user-defined class can act as a type.

Comment: There are many names for that, depending on the structure. In this case, we could probably call it "**useless**" since there is no setter or getter for it. If it had a getter, we could call it a very basic **linked list**, since you can iterate from the first to the last by calling `getNext()` until you get null. In other cases, a class having one or more of itself as members could model, for example, a **parent->child(ren)** relationship. Or for example, a `Person` class might have another `Person` member (for example, as "Boss", "Next of kin", etc.etc.).

Comment: in your `line 2 : int number` is also similar to `Integer number` where Integer is also a class ;)

Comment: The short Q&A format of this site is unsuitable for teaching programming basics. You would do better to use other resources.

Answer (score 3):

This just means you have member of type `CupNode`, its not different from having `int` or `String` as a member.

You can access all the functionality of this member as you could have done when creating an instance in main

```
CupNode cup = new CupNode(2, 2);
cup.getNumber(); // call getNumber() in cup
cup.getNext().getNumber(); // call getNumber() in next member in cup
```

And the getter for `next` will look like

```
public CupNode getNext() {
    return next;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Object-oriented Programming (OOP), it is *all* about creating classes and objects and messing around with them. It's super fun!

As you already know, `int`, `double`, `float` etc. are data types. In fact, they are classified as *primitive types*. You might also have heard of `String`. Believe it or not, `String` is the name of a class! These "class name types" are called *reference types*.

Let's use `String` for an example:

```
String a = "Hello";
```

When you create a variable which is of a reference type and initialize it with some value, you are actually creating a *new instance* of that class. In the above example, you are creating a new instance of `String` i.e. a new string. This new instance is referred to as an *object*.

So in your case, your `CupNode` is a class. And you can create a new instance of it like this:

```
CupNode node = new CupNode (0, 20);
```

"Wait wait wait! What is *that*?" you shouted. `new CupNode(0, 20)` represents a new instance of `CupNode`. And the two numbers are the parameters, which are defined here:

```
public CupNode(int number, int capacity) { // <--- here
    this.number = number;
    this.capacity = capacity;
    this.next=null;
}
```

What can you do with an object?

You see those methods that you defined in the class, like `getNumber`, `getCapacity`? When you have created an object, you can call those methods with your object!

```
System.out.println(node.getNumber());
```

Objects are very useful in Java. Here are more examples:

When you want to accept user input from the console, you can

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); // System.in represents the console's input stream
String input = sc.nextLine();
```

When you want to create a window,

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

When you want to store a really large integer that's larger than the max of `long`

```
BigInteger myInt = new BigInteger("9.9999e99");
```

When you want to create an array that has a dynamic size:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<> ();
list.add("Hello");
```

There are just so MUCH stuff you can do with classes!